# Is there a way to select a random cell from an HTML table and change its background color?

Tags: random, html-table, formatting

I need to randomly select a single cell from a 5X5 table and change its background color. I would like to do this by choosing a random index location in the table.

I want to do this:

```
table > tr:nth-child(Random Number between 1 and 5) > td:nth-child(Random number between 1 and 5){
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

I figured it out. Used this:

```
let selected = document.getElementById("table").rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)].cells[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
selected.id = "selected";
```

Ideally I would generate the random numbers, one for the  and one for the  in javascript and then pass the value to the css style sheet.

Comment: Kept working on it and figured it out:

Comment: let selected = document.getElementById("table").rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)].cells[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];                                                        
selected.id = "selected";

Answer (score 0):

assign an id to the tds and make an array that contain the ids of these cells choose randomly from the array and change the style color of the cell matching the id

you might need to use javascript

PS if my answer helped you please upvote or choose it as answer if it was what you're looking for